# Corrupt member variable name in bootstrap.php.cache

Tags: symfony, nginx, php, xubuntu

I've a problem with Symfony2 on Xubuntu since I installed it few hours ago: my Symfony project keep saying me :

```
Notice: Corrupt member variable name in /.../app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2346
```

I tried everything: rebuild the file, remove this particular line (it has the same problem on another line), remove it and copy it from elsewhere.

The problem stays. And it drives me crazy. Even worse, any other PHP project works well; I use phpMyAdmin without problems.

I use nginx + PHP-FPM and my PHP version is :

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 06:56:34) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

I can access to the site on the first load after a rebuild of the file, then it bugs. According to some things I found on Internet, it seems to be a problem of null-byte or something like that.

Has anyone already experienced a problem like that? How could I solve it?

Thanks by advance,

Titouan Galopin

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clear the cache ?

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: I do have deleted the cache. The thing is it doesn't seems to be a cache problem as even if I empty the cache, the bootstrap.php.cache file stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in PHP.

It occurs if the class has a static field and the name of this field is one character.

Like this:

```
class Test{
    static private $a=false;
}
```